# Is it possible to use CSS classes in mailer template?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, email

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.1.0 and I would like to know if it is possible to use CSS classes in mailer templates (`.html.erb`). At this time, in order to style emails, I am using HTML code like the following:

```
<div style="margin: 4px 0 12px;">
  <span style="font-size: 14px;">
    ...
  </span>
</div>
```

So, **is it possible to use CSS classes in mailer templates? If so, *where* and *how* I should state and use those classes?**

Comment: There is no such thing as a CSS class. Things that have been incorrectly referred to as "CSS classes" include HTML classes, CSS class selectors, CSS selectors, CSS rule-sets, CSS rules and CSS properties.

Answer (score 2):

Code like it's 1995, because email clients (particularly Outlook 2007, Gmail, Hotmail) support a very limited set of HTML elements and CSS attributes. Use tables, inline styles, presentation elements (i.e. `<b>` instead of `font-weight:bold`).

Useful links on coding for email:

- http://www.sitepoint.com/code-html-email-newsletters/
- http://kb.mailchimp.com/article/how-to-code-html-emails
- http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

Answer (score 1):

Stylesheets have a tendency to be stripped by some mail clients (especially with web mail services) so the use of style attributes is recommended instead.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. ERB allows you to write any HTML you would normally.

However, because it's email and clients are notoriously bad at rendering CSS consistently, you should use inline formatting as you have in your example. (I know that's horrible).

You could insert a `<style>.myclass { color: red; }</style>` at the top of the mailer template and then use `<div class="mclass">` in the template, but chances are that this style tag will be removed by the client.

Answer (score 0):

You're lucky because there's a gem called [Roadie](https://github.com/Mange/roadie) that solves this problem elegantly. See the RailsCasts episode [Sending HTML Email](http://railscasts.com/episodes/312-sending-html-email) for more information.